# How do I require my custom class in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have `database.js` where my `Database` class is.

**database.js**

```
class Database {
    constructor() {
        this.uri = "mongodb+srv: ....."
    }
    get_uri = () => {
        return this.uri
    }
    connect = async client => {
        await client.connect();
        console.log("Successfully connected!")
        return client;
    }

    disconnect = async client => {
        await client.close();
    }
}

exports.Database = new Database()
```

**server.js**

```
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');
const db = require("./server/database");
const connect = db.connect(); // TypeError: db.connect is not a function
```

`files`

```
server -|
        |-database.js

package.json
server.js
```

`printed db variable` for my code above

```
[0] Database object:
[0] {
[0]   Database: Database {
[0]     get_uri: [Function: get_uri],
[0]     connect: [AsyncFunction: connect],
[0]     disconnect: [AsyncFunction: disconnect],
[0]     uri: 'mongodb+srv:......'
[0]   }
[0] }
```

**EDIT 1**

Soulka, just done this:

```
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');
const { Database } = require("./server/database");
const connect = Database.connect();
```

and still `TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined`

But it raises an error, which I put as a comment above. What I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: your file ist Database.js not database.js. use const db = require("./server/Database"); Also your db.connect() is an async function. You might want to await it.

Comment: @SoulKa oh, it's database.js, edited!

Comment: can you try to print out the db object in server.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your import should be `const { Database } = require("./server/database");` instead of `const db = require("./server/database");`

This is because you are exporting via `exports.Database = ..` not `exports = ...`

**EDIT (for your edit):**
I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but you should think about using a singleton like this:

```js
class Database {
    constructor() {
        this.uri = "mongodb+srv: ....."
    }

    static get instance() {
        if (!Database._instance) Database._instance = new Database();
        return Database._instance;
    }

    get_uri = () => {
        return this.uri
    }
    connect = async client => {
        await client.connect();
        console.log("Successfully connected!")
        return client;
    }

    disconnect = async client => {
        await client.close();
    }
}

exports.Database = Database
```

And then in server.js

```js
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');
const { Database }= require("./server/database");
const db = Database.instance;
const connect = db.connect( someClientMustGoHere ); // <---- THIS LINE
```

**EDIT 2:** Fixed the last line of server.js to be `const connect = db.connect( someClientMustGoHere );`

Comment: About bold edit  - still ` Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined`, and `printed db variable` is same

Comment: you are forgetting to pass the client to the `connect( client )` function! It must be `db.connect( someClient );` Maybe assign the client to the Database instance so it can be accessed via `this.client`?